# How do you explain whats going on in Ruby here. 'hello'.match('(.)\1')[0]?

Tags: ruby

In the Ruby documentation, it explains:

```
'hello'.match('(.)\1')[0]   #=> "ll"
```

How is it that `(.)\1` picks out "ll"? I've replaced "hello" with other words which include double letters, like "goodbye" and "cheese", and I see that it keeps picking out the double letters.

Then I've also extended the string with more double letters, and added more .s in the brackets such as:

```
puts 'boooooo'.match('(...)\1')  #=> oooooo
```

So I see that . corresponds to any character. But why does it return letters which are doubled?

Thanks

Comment: First note that if [String#match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-match)'s argument is a string Ruby converts it to a regular expression: `Regexp.new('(.)\1') #=> /(.)\1/`. This would more commonly be written `'hello'[/(.)\1/] #=> "ll`, which uses the method [String#[\]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Answer (score 2):

You met backreferences. They match the same text as previously matched by a capturing group (in your first example your capturing group, what is inside parantheses, is `.`, any character), and precisely `\1` refers to the first capturing group.

https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html